# Split Strings into values in long dataframe format

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, stringr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like the following example `df` which consist of a character variable `VAR`.

```
df<-data.frame(ID = 1:2, 
               VAR = c("VAL1\r\nVAL2\r\nVAL8","VAL2\r\nVAL5"),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#     ID                  VAR
# 1    1 VAL1\r\nVAL2\r\nVAL8
# 2    2         VAL2\r\nVAL5
```

I would like to split the character variable by the return carriage - newline `\r\n` and obtain the desired dataframe below:

```
#    ID   VAR
# 1    1 VAL1
# 2    1 VAL2
# 3    1 VAL8
# 4    2 VAL2
# 5    2 VAL5
```

I wrote the code as follows, but I somehow got lost in the `gather` function while trying to change the format of the data frame into a long format.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
  bind_cols(as.data.frame(str_split(df$VAR,"\r\n",simplify = TRUE))) %>%
  select(-VAR) %>%
  gather(key,value)
```

Please advise.

Comment: @Sotos How is this a duplicate of the linked one?

Comment: @akrun Isn't it? If I do this `cSplit(df, "VAR", "\r\n", "long")` which is an answer in the linked dupe I get the expected result

Comment: I meant the sep is not the same.

Comment: Oh of course. Also the data frame is called `mydf` instead of `df`. Better open a new question about that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df, VAR, sep='\\s+')
```